# Need help condensing my code so it takes up less lines and it easier to interpret

Tags: javascript, html, css

Description is at the bottom

Here is a link to all the code: [Link](https://github.com/WartyWarthog123/Timetable)

```html
<body>
    <h3>Timetable</h3>
    <form id="dataForm">
      <table id="table1">
        <tr>
          <td>Week A</td>
          <td>Monday</td>
          <td>Tuesday</td>
          <td>Wednesday</td>
          <td>Thursday</td>
          <td>Friday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Period 1</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Class Info" id="d1p1w1" name="d1p1w1">
            <select id="colors0" name="colors">
            <option value="color0" selected output>Colour:</option>
            <option value="color1">Red</option>
            <option value="color2">Yellow</option>
            <option value="color3">Green</option>
            <option value="color4">Purple</option>
            <option value="color5">Grey</option>
            <option value="color6">Blue</option>
          </select>
            &#8203 &#8203
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Class Info" id="d2p1w1" name="d2p1w1">
            <select id="colors1" name="colors2">
              <option value="color0" selected output>Colour:</option>
              <option value="color1">Red</option>
              <option value="color2">Yellow</option>
              <option value="color3">Green</option>
              <option value="color4">Purple</option>
              <option value="color5">Grey</option>
              <option value="color6">Blue</option>
            </select>
              &#8203 &#8203
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Class Info" id="d3p1w1" name="d3p1w1">
            <select id="colors2" name="colors3">
              <option value="color0" selected output>Colour:</option>
              <option value="color1">Red</option>
              <option value="color2">Yellow</option>
              <option value="color3">Green</option>
              <option value="color4">Purple</option>
              <option value="color5">Grey</option>
              <option value="color6">Blue</option>
            </select>
              &#8203 &#8203
```

```html
<table id="dataTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Week A</td>
          <td>Monday</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Tuesday</td>
          <td>Wednesday</td>
          <td>Thursday</td>
          <td>Friday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9:23</td>
          <th id="d0">
            <span id="day1p1w1"></span>
            <script>
              document.getElementById('colors0').onchange=changeEventHandler;

              var indicator = document.getElementById("d0");
              
              function changeEventHandler() {
                indicator.classList = this.value;
              }
            </script>
          </th>
          <td>8:53</td>
          <th id="d1">
            <span id="day2p1w1"></span>
            <script>
              document.getElementById('colors1').onchange=changeEventHandler;

              var indicator1 = document.getElementById("d1");
              
              function changeEventHandler() {
                  indicator1.classList = this.value;
              }
            </script>
          </th>
```

```css
        select option[value="color0"] {
          background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        select option[value="color1"] {
          background-color: #ffdfde;
        }
        select option[value="color2"] {
          background-color: #ffffdf;
        }
        select option[value="color3"] {
          background-color: #dfffde;
        }
        select option[value="color4"] {
          background-color: #efdeff;
        }
        select option[value="color5"] {
          background-color: #e6efef;
        }
        select option[value="color6"] {
          background-color: #dffffe;
        }


        .color0 {background-color: #ffffff;}
        .color1 {background-color: #ffdfde;}
        .color2 {background-color: #ffffdf;}
        .color3 {background-color: #dfffde;}
        .color4 {background-color: #efdeff;}
        .color5 {background-color: #e6efef;}
        .color6 {background-color: #dffffe;}
```

```javascript
<script>
function displayData() {
const d1p1w1 = document.getElementById("d1p1w1").value;
const d2p1w1 = document.getElementById("d2p1w1").value;
const d3p1w1 = document.getElementById("d3p1w1").value;
const d4p1w1 = document.getElementById("d4p1w1").value;
const d5p1w1 = document.getElementById("d5p1w1").value;
const d1p2w1 = document.getElementById("d1p2w1").value;
const d2p2w1 = document.getElementById("d2p2w1").value;
const d3p2w1 = document.getElementById("d3p2w1").value;
const d4p2w1 = document.getElementById("d4p2w1").value;
const d5p2w1 = document.getElementById("d5p2w1").value;
const d1p3w1 = document.getElementById("d1p3w1").value;
const d2p3w1 = document.getElementById("d2p3w1").value;
const d3p3w1 = document.getElementById("d3p3w1").value;
const d4p3w1 = document.getElementById("d4p3w1").value;
const d5p3w1 = document.getElementById("d5p3w1").value;
const d1p4w1 = document.getElementById("d1p4w1").value;
const d2p4w1 = document.getElementById("d2p4w1").value;
const d3p4w1 = document.getElementById("d3p4w1").value;
const d4p4w1 = document.getElementById("d4p4w1").value;
const d5p4w1 = document.getElementById("d5p4w1").value;
const d1p5w1 = document.getElementById("d1p5w1").value;
const d2p5w1 = document.getElementById("d2p5w1").value;
const d3p5w1 = document.getElementById("d3p5w1").value;
const d4p5w1 = document.getElementById("d4p5w1").value;
const d5p5w1 = document.getElementById("d5p5w1").value;
const d1p6w1 = document.getElementById("d1p6w1").value;
const d2p6w1 = document.getElementById("d2p6w1").value;
const d3p6w1 = document.getElementById("d3p6w1").value;
const d4p6w1 = document.getElementById("d4p6w1").value;
const d5p6w1 = document.getElementById("d5p6w1").value;

const d1p1w2 = document.getElementById("d1p1w2").value;
const d2p1w2 = document.getElementById("d2p1w2").value;
const d3p1w2 = document.getElementById("d3p1w2").value;
const d4p1w2 = document.getElementById("d4p1w2").value;
const d5p1w2 = document.getElementById("d5p1w2").value;
const d1p2w2 = document.getElementById("d1p2w2").value;
const d2p2w2 = document.getElementById("d2p2w2").value;
const d3p2w2 = document.getElementById("d3p2w2").value;
const d4p2w2 = document.getElementById("d4p2w2").value;
const d5p2w2 = document.getElementById("d5p2w2").value;
const d1p3w2 = document.getElementById("d1p3w2").value;
const d2p3w2 = document.getElementById("d2p3w2").value;
const d3p3w2 = document.getElementById("d3p3w2").value;
const d4p3w2 = document.getElementById("d4p3w2").value;
const d5p3w2 = document.getElementById("d5p3w2").value;
const d1p4w2 = document.getElementById("d1p4w2").value;
const d2p4w2 = document.getElementById("d2p4w2").value;
const d3p4w2 = document.getElementById("d3p4w2").value;
const d4p4w2 = document.getElementById("d4p4w2").value;
const d5p4w2 = document.getElementById("d5p4w2").value;
const d1p5w2 = document.getElementById("d1p5w2").value;
const d2p5w2 = document.getElementById("d2p5w2").value;
const d3p5w2 = document.getElementById("d3p5w2").value;
const d4p5w2 = document.getElementById("d4p5w2").value;
const d5p5w2 = document.getElementById("d5p5w2").value;
const d1p6w2 = document.getElementById("d1p6w2").value;
const d2p6w2 = document.getElementById("d2p6w2").value;
const d3p6w2 = document.getElementById("d3p6w2").value;
const d4p6w2 = document.getElementById("d4p6w2").value;
const d5p6w2 = document.getElementById("d5p6w2").value;

const data = {
    d1p1w1: d1p1w1,
    d2p1w1: d2p1w1,
    d3p1w1: d3p1w1,
    d4p1w1: d4p1w1,
    d5p1w1: d5p1w1,
    d1p2w1: d1p2w1,
    d2p2w1: d2p2w1,
    d3p2w1: d3p2w1,
    d4p2w1: d4p2w1,
    d5p2w1: d5p2w1,
    d1p3w1: d1p3w1,
    d2p3w1: d2p3w1,
    d3p3w1: d3p3w1,
    d4p3w1: d4p3w1,
    d5p3w1: d5p3w1,
    d1p4w1: d1p4w1,
    d2p4w1: d2p4w1,
    d3p4w1: d3p4w1,
    d4p4w1: d4p4w1,
    d5p4w1: d5p4w1,
    d1p5w1: d1p5w1,
    d2p5w1: d2p5w1,
    d3p5w1: d3p5w1,
    d4p5w1: d4p5w1,
    d5p5w1: d5p5w1,
    d1p6w1: d1p6w1,
    d2p6w1: d2p6w1,
    d3p6w1: d3p6w1,
    d4p6w1: d4p6w1,
    d5p6w1: d5p6w1,

    d1p1w2: d1p1w2,
    d2p1w2: d2p1w2,
    d3p1w2: d3p1w2,
    d4p1w2: d4p1w2,
    d5p1w2: d5p1w2,
    d1p2w2: d1p2w2,
    d2p2w2: d2p2w2,
    d3p2w2: d3p2w2,
    d4p2w2: d4p2w2,
    d5p2w2: d5p2w2,
    d1p3w2: d1p3w2,
    d2p3w2: d2p3w2,
    d3p3w2: d3p3w2,
    d4p3w2: d4p3w2,
    d5p3w2: d5p3w2,
    d1p4w2: d1p4w2,
    d2p4w2: d2p4w2,
    d3p4w2: d3p4w2,
    d4p4w2: d4p4w2,
    d5p4w2: d5p4w2,
    d1p5w2: d1p5w2,
    d2p5w2: d2p5w2,
    d3p5w2: d3p5w2,
    d4p5w2: d4p5w2,
    d5p5w2: d5p5w2,
    d1p6w2: d1p6w2,
    d2p6w2: d2p6w2,
    d3p6w2: d3p6w2,
    d4p6w2: d4p6w2,
    d5p6w2: d5p6w2,
};


document.getElementById('day1p1w1').innerHTML = d1p1w1;
document.getElementById('day2p1w1').innerHTML = d2p1w1;
document.getElementById('day3p1w1').innerHTML = d3p1w1;
document.getElementById('day4p1w1').innerHTML = d4p1w1;
document.getElementById('day5p1w1').innerHTML = d5p1w1;
document.getElementById('day1p2w1').innerHTML = d1p2w1;
document.getElementById('day2p2w1').innerHTML = d2p2w1;
document.getElementById('day3p2w1').innerHTML = d3p2w1;
document.getElementById('day4p2w1').innerHTML = d4p2w1;
document.getElementById('day5p2w1').innerHTML = d5p2w1;
document.getElementById('day1p3w1').innerHTML = d1p3w1;
document.getElementById('day2p3w1').innerHTML = d2p3w1;
document.getElementById('day3p3w1').innerHTML = d3p3w1;
document.getElementById('day4p3w1').innerHTML = d4p3w1;
document.getElementById('day5p3w1').innerHTML = d5p3w1;
document.getElementById('day1p4w1').innerHTML = d1p4w1;
document.getElementById('day2p4w1').innerHTML = d2p4w1;
document.getElementById('day3p4w1').innerHTML = d3p4w1;
document.getElementById('day4p4w1').innerHTML = d4p4w1;
document.getElementById('day5p4w1').innerHTML = d5p4w1;
document.getElementById('day1p5w1').innerHTML = d1p5w1;
document.getElementById('day2p5w1').innerHTML = d2p5w1;
document.getElementById('day3p5w1').innerHTML = d3p5w1;
document.getElementById('day4p5w1').innerHTML = d4p5w1;
document.getElementById('day5p5w1').innerHTML = d5p5w1;
document.getElementById('day1p6w1').innerHTML = d1p6w1;
document.getElementById('day2p6w1').innerHTML = d2p6w1;
document.getElementById('day3p6w1').innerHTML = d3p6w1;
document.getElementById('day4p6w1').innerHTML = d4p6w1;
document.getElementById('day5p6w1').innerHTML = d5p6w1;

document.getElementById('day1p1w2').innerHTML = d1p1w2;
document.getElementById('day2p1w2').innerHTML = d2p1w2;
document.getElementById('day3p1w2').innerHTML = d3p1w2;
document.getElementById('day4p1w2').innerHTML = d4p1w2;
document.getElementById('day5p1w2').innerHTML = d5p1w2;
document.getElementById('day1p2w2').innerHTML = d1p2w2;
document.getElementById('day2p2w2').innerHTML = d2p2w2;
document.getElementById('day3p2w2').innerHTML = d3p2w2;
document.getElementById('day4p2w2').innerHTML = d4p2w2;
document.getElementById('day5p2w2').innerHTML = d5p2w2;
document.getElementById('day1p3w2').innerHTML = d1p3w2;
document.getElementById('day2p3w2').innerHTML = d2p3w2;
document.getElementById('day3p3w2').innerHTML = d3p3w2;
document.getElementById('day4p3w2').innerHTML = d4p3w2;
document.getElementById('day5p3w2').innerHTML = d5p3w2;
document.getElementById('day1p4w2').innerHTML = d1p4w2;
document.getElementById('day2p4w2').innerHTML = d2p4w2;
document.getElementById('day3p4w2').innerHTML = d3p4w2;
document.getElementById('day4p4w2').innerHTML = d4p4w2;
document.getElementById('day5p4w2').innerHTML = d5p4w2;
document.getElementById('day1p5w2').innerHTML = d1p5w2;
document.getElementById('day2p5w2').innerHTML = d2p5w2;
document.getElementById('day3p5w2').innerHTML = d3p5w2;
document.getElementById('day4p5w2').innerHTML = d4p5w2;
document.getElementById('day5p5w2').innerHTML = d5p5w2;
document.getElementById('day1p6w2').innerHTML = d1p6w2;
document.getElementById('day2p6w2').innerHTML = d2p6w2;
document.getElementById('day3p6w2').innerHTML = d3p6w2;
document.getElementById('day4p6w2').innerHTML = d4p6w2;
document.getElementById('day5p6w2').innerHTML = d5p6w2;

document.getElementById("d1p1w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p1w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p1w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p1w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p1w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p2w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p2w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p2w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p2w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p2w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p3w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p3w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p3w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p3w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p3w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p4w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p4w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p4w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p4w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p4w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p5w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p5w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p5w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p5w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p5w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p6w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p6w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p6w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p6w1").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p6w1").value = "";

document.getElementById("d1p1w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p1w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p1w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p1w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p1w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p2w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p2w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p2w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p2w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p2w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p3w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p3w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p3w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p3w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p3w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p4w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p4w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p4w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p4w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p4w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p5w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p5w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p5w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p5w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p5w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d1p6w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d2p6w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d3p6w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d4p6w2").value = "";
document.getElementById("d5p6w2").value = "";

document.getElementById("dataForm").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("dataTable").style.display = "inline";
}
</script>
```

The first block of code is the input table, it continues repeating for many more lines of code (you can see this in the Java code); it looks like this in the final website: [input table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXhVh.png).

The second block of code is the output table, it also continues repeating for many more lines of code; it looks like this in the final website: [output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HatFV.png).

The third block of code is just the CSS for the colour picker.

The fourth block of code is the JavaScript that takes the value from the first table and puts in the second table.

The whole website is front end (I think that's the term) and I would like to keep it front end if possible.

Is there a way to condense this code?

Comment: I was one of the reviewers that closed your question at StackOverflow. I'm glad that you followed the advice to ask this question here at Code Review! I'm unsure if I can do the review and refactoring today but you can expect it until the end of the week.

Comment: PS One thing to mention, Java is **not** a shortform for JavaScript. JavaScript and Java were released nearly at the same time and are 2 different languages. JavaScript is a scripting language that runs live while Java is an object-orientated language that needs to be compiled.

Comment: It looks like the code you included is incomplete (I see opening tags that aren't closed). Can you include the rest of the code in your question?

Comment: I added a link to github at the top that has the full code if anyone needs it

Comment: Welcome! [State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In 10 words or less, what does your code _do_?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to be kinda lazy about this, because I think I can outline the general strategy to use but I don't have time right now to put together a real solution (and I don't work in javascript much anyway).

Basically, you're doing the same sequence of actions to a schematize batch of things. There are a number of ways to do this, but I think most of the good ones are going to involve nesting `foreach` blocks. For example:

```javascript
ds = [1,2,3,4,5];
ps = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
ws = [1,2];

data = {}

ds.foreach(d => {
  ps.foreach(p => {
    ws.foreach(w => {
      let dpw = "d" + d.toString() + "p" + p.toString() +"w" + w.toString();
      let daypw = "day" + d.toString() + "p" + p.toString() +"w" + w.toString();
      let source = document.getElementById(dpw);
      let target = document.getElementById(daypw);
      let val = source.value;
      data[dpw] = val;
      target.innerHTML = val;
      source.value = "";
    });
  });
});

document.getElementById("dataForm").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("dataTable").style.display = "inline";
```

Comment: One thing to add, you should not use `innerHTML` nowadays as it is comparable slow and can pose security risks. Especially in this case `textContent` wouldd be the better choice. it also could be cleaner if you sue backticks to write vriabels or functions directly in a string instead of concatenating it. Instead of suing iterating arrays you should use a `for` or `while` loop.